# MongoDB authentication in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

Is anywhere article, video or something about how to implement Authorization (login, register) by MongoDB.Identity packages, step by step ?

I found github, but there is full of files which make chaos.
I want implemented register and login feature for MongoDB like SQL authorization.

Please, anybody help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, nobody know nothing about it ? I have multiple problems with make it this feature from A to Z.